# "As" Angular ng-controller not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

The [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) makes me think that below, I should be using `ng-click="ctrl.nextDay()"` due to `"GameController as ctrl"`. However, in that case, nothing happens and no errors are reported. Just `ng-click="nextDay()"` works though.

```
<div ng-controller="GameController as ctrl" >
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  ng-click="nextDay()" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward" aria-hidden="true">Next Day
    </button>
</div>
```

The controller is defined as follows:

```
angular.module('FEModule')
.controller('GameController', ['$scope', '$http', '$fancyModal',
    function($scope, $http, $fancyModal) {

        console.log("GameController is instantiated! Yeah.");

        $scope.nextDay = function() {
                console.log("this is next day function!");                      
        }
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: It all depends on what nextDay is. Is it a function attached to the $scope (nextDay()), or to the controller (ctrl.nextDay()). Check the code of the controller. It matters.

Comment: Also, where did `theGame` come from?  You're not following the conventions laid out for your own controller here.

Comment: Cleaned up the code and added controller definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nextDay() is a function of the $scope. So it's not attached to the controller, and is accessed in the view, like any other function on the scope, using `nextDay()`.

If you want to make it a function attached to the controller, and thus use `ctrl.nextDay()` in the view, the code in the controller must be

```
    this.nextDay = function() {
        console.log("this is next day function!");                      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind nextDay() to the controller instance or remove `controller as` syntax and use $scope.

**Solution A**

```
    <div ng-controller="GameController as ctrl" >
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  ng-click="ctrl.nextDay()" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward" aria-hidden="true">Next Day
    </button>
</div>
```

**Solution B**

```
<div ng-controller="GameController" >
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  ng-click="nextDay()" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward" aria-hidden="true">Next Day
    </button>
</div>
```